# Adding first occurence column to groupy dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this-

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'DT':[1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1],'city':['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B'],'O':[22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99]})
```

Now for each unique city, I want to add up all the values in the O column first occurring in the Dt column.
Output-

```
   city  O
0   A   77
1   B   88
```

Explanation-
For the city 'A' the first unique occurring DT is 1 so we add the corresponding O column value that is 22. Next for the same city 'A' the first occurring 2 in the DT column is the 4th row so we add its corresponding O column== 22+55=77. Similarly for city B since only 1 is there in DT column the O will be 88.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `drop_duplicates` and then `groupby`

```
df1  = (

 df.drop_duplicates(subset=["DT", "city"], keep="first")
    .groupby("city")["O"]
    .sum()
    .reset_index()
)
```

---

```
print(df1)

 city   O
0    A  77
1    B  88
```

or you could use a double group by first using `first` then `sum`

```
df.groupby(["city", "DT"]).first().groupby(level=0).sum().reset_index()

  city   O
0    A  77
1    B  88
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also extract the first lines and sum with `level`:

```
df.groupby(['DT','city'])['O'].first().sum(level=1)
```

Output:

```
city
A    77
B    88
Name: O, dtype: int64
```